# Incompatibility between Conky and Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-sdk, cinnamon, conky

I am on 16.04 (+ Cinnamon) and I have a strange behaviour since I installed Ubuntu SDK : all my settings in Conky is displayed with squares like my fonts were no longer considered.

I checked and these are always present in my /home/ME/.fonts directory and my .conkyrc has not changed.

Is it possible that the installation has changed the LUA packages, something in the configuration ? Has anyone had this problem ?

Not a big deal but thank you in advance :)

Franck

Ps : Here my wonderfull screenshot with these ugly squares ...

[image]

Comment: What version number does `conky -v` reveal?

Comment: It's " conky 1.10.1 "

Answer (score 0):

Conky 1.10.1 has all kinds of problems for myself and others. Downgrading to Conky 1.9 seems the simplest solution. To downgrade and freeze Conky at version 1.9 use:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge conky-std conky-all
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/conky/conky-all_1.9.0-6build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi conky-all_1.9.0-6build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-mark hold conky-all
```

Comment: I confirm, after uninstalling the SDK, that I no longer have the problem. I'll try the Conky downgrade and SDK's reinstall. Thank you

Comment: @DansLeRuSH If after uninstalling the SDK conky is still at version 1.10.1 and working perfectly then there is no need to downgrade to version 1.9.

Comment: Just in case I want to re-install the SDK to produce other things than webapps for Ubuntu Touch ;)